# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español para referirse a la acción de hacer dos o más tareas a la vez?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

En algunos lenguajes (chino, y creo que inglés también) existe una palabra para referirse a la acción de hacer dos o más tareas a la vez. ¿Existe alguna palabra así en español?

Comment: "Sincronizar" significa "hacer que coincidan en el tiempo dos o más movimientos o fenómenos", no sé si podría valer. ¿"Sincronizar las tareas"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Creo que se entendería otra cosa de *sincronizar tareas*.

Comment: Simultáneamente, hacer dos cosas simultáneamente. Simultaneidad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La palabra "**[multitarea](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/multitarea)**", aunque no aparece como tal en el diccionario de la RAE por ser una palabra compuesta, existe en español y se usa exactamente en el sentido que indicas (también para personas: es común escuchar que "[las mujeres son multitarea](https://www.google.es/search?q=mujeres%20multitarea)", aunque sea un tópico algo sexista). Eso sí, funciona normalmente como adjetivo o, si acaso, sustantivo.

De lo que no estoy seguro es de que haya un verbo que signifique "hacer varias cosas a la vez", que creo que es lo que buscas.
Lo más parecido sería quizá **concurrir** (por aquello de que multitarea es cuando varias tareas se llevan a cabo de manera concurrente), pero no termina de cuadrar:

> **[concurrir](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=concurrir)**
>
> Del lat. *concurrĕre*.
>
> 1. intr. Dicho de diferentes personas, sucesos o cosas: Juntarse en un mismo lugar o tiempo.
> 2. intr. Dicho de diferentes cualidades o circunstancias: Coincidir en alguien o en algo.

Otros verbos que podrías usar: **solapar** tareas, **agrupar** tareas, **unificar** tareas. Cada cual con sus matices, pueden cuadrar con el uso que necesitas, aunque ninguno al 100%.

Comment: **Multitarea** es una palabra compuesta y por eso no aparece en la RAE lo que no significa "no reconocida" Existe el prefijo [multi](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=multi-) y el sustantivo [tarea](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=tarea) por lo tanto _multitarea_ si está reconocida por la RAE aunque no figure directamente en el diccionario. +1

Comment: Buen ejemplo de cómo se usa el sustantivo *multitarea*: http://es.wikihow.com/dejar-de-hacer-multitareas

Answer (score 5):

[**Simultanear**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XwDfjJ6)

> 1. tr. Realizar en el mismo espacio de tiempo dos operaciones o propósitos.

junto con [**simultaneidad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XwEPyXV)

> 1. f. Cualidad de simultáneo.

[**simultáneo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XwH9oMz)

> 1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que se hace u ocurre al mismo tiempo que otra.

y  [**simultánemente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XwATqV7)

> 1. adv. De manera simultánea.

son opciones correctas (verbo, sustantivo, adjetivo y adverbio) para lo preguntado por OP.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! _Simultanear_ parece una buena opción. Y bienvenido/a al sitio.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es demasiado tarde, pero esta es la palabra que buscas: "**polivalencia**".

Comment: Podrías agregar alguna definición de qué significa la palabra para que tu pregunta sea más completa.

Comment: Polivalente se refiere a la "capacidad de hacer más de una cosa" más no necesariamente al mismo tiempo.